# Canvas Power App to upload file to Salesforce using Rest API

Tags: salesforce, rest, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am a newbie to PowerApps and the flow automations. I am building a simple Canvas Power App that receives the user input then the JSON is composed and the JSON is posted to the Salesforce using the REST API through the flows. Submit button action is like below

```
Collect(
     FormInfo,   {
         name: nameInput.Text,
         title: titleInput.Text,
         manager: managerInput.Text,
         phoneNumber: phoneNumInput.Text,
         email: emailInput.Text,
         startDate: Text(startDateInput.SelectedDate),
         roleProfileInfo: roleProfileInfoInput.Text,
         userSubmitting: User().Email   }
 );
 Set(FormObj,JSON(FormInfo));
    
 SFNewUserRequest_1.Run(FormObj);
    
    
 Reset(nameInput);
 Reset(titleInput);
 Reset(managerInput);
 Reset(phoneNumInput);
 Reset(emailInput);
 Reset(startDateInput);
 Reset(roleProfileInfoInput);
```

The user input is composed as JSON and sending it to the flow. I am not sure how I can add an upload file in the power app that needs to be sent to Salesforce through the REST service. Most of the examples out there are doing the loading the file to Sharepoint library, I just wanted to know if this is also ossible.

Comment: What type of files? .jpg, .png, .xlsx, .pdf, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. In some cases, you have to get creative to parse out the correct Base64 encoded image data (if attempting to pass .jpg/.png's to Power Automate).

**Here is some code I use `OnSelect` of a `Save` button after user selects an image using the `Add Media` control:**

```
Set(varFileExt, Right(btnAddMedia.FileName, 3));

Collect(colPhotoForFlow,
    {
        projectGUID: varGUID,
        picUri: imgAddedMedia.Image,
        picFilename:
            If(
                btnAddMedia.FileName = "image.jpg",
                Concatenate(
                    Text(Now(), "[$-en-US]yyyy-mm-dd_hhmmss"),
                    ".jpg"
                ),
                btnAddMedia.FileName
            ),
        fileExtension: varFileExt,
        picJSON: 
            If(
                Or(
                    Lower(varFileExt) = "jpg",
                    Lower(varFileExt) = "jpeg"
                ),
                    Mid(JSON(imgAddedMedia.Image, IncludeBinaryData), 25, Len(JSON(imgAddedMedia.Image, IncludeBinaryData)) - 25),
                
                Lower(varFileExt) = "png",
                    Mid(JSON(imgAddedMedia.Image, IncludeBinaryData), 24, Len(JSON(imgAddedMedia.Image, IncludeBinaryData)) - 24)
            ),
        picCaption: txtCaption.Text
    }
);

Reset(txtCaption);
Reset(btnAddMedia)
```

**Theres a lot of (valuable) stuff to unpack here:**

- `varFileExt` is used because .jpg's have 4 characters in their Base64 header ("jpeg" whereas .png's have only 3 "png")

  - Hence the `Mid(25)` vs `Mid(24)` for Base64 parsing
- If user is on mobile device and they **take** a picture using the app, PowerApps will autoname the image `image.jpg`

  - Hence the `If()` statement for file naming

**Here is some code I use `OnSelect` of a final `Submit` button after user is done uploading images:**

```
Set(varUploadPhotos, JSON(colPhotoForFlow, IncludeBinaryData));
PA_PICS_TO_ENDPOINT.Run(varUploadPhotos)
```

You can adapt this for other file types as well.

Comment: Thanks a ton, This really helps... Can I pass along with this image details other field data in to the same JSON?

Comment: Also what is the control I should be using here? I am not connecting to Sharepoint library instead I am trying to directly connect to the Salesforce. Most of the blogs shows how to connect to Sharepont library using the attachment control, and I cannot see the attachment control by default

Comment: **RE:** `Can I pass along with this image details...`: Yes. The reference collection shown in my answer has things like `picCaption` and `projectGUID`; metadata corresponding to each image.

Comment: **RE:** `What is the control I should be using here...`: I often use the `Add Picture` control (`Insert/Media/Add Picture`). This will pull in a grouped control consisting of a button and a preview image. In the code above, `btnAddMedia.Filename` refers to the button and `imgAddedMedia.Image` refers to the preview image.

Comment: Can you please help me understand what is `txtCaption` here and also `varGUID` they both are erroring out

Comment: `txtCaption` is the name of a Text Control within my PowerApp. The `txt` prefix is a naming convention that shows at-a-glance what type of control you're working with. `varGUID` is a Variable defined within the PowerApp. Here, the `var` prefix shows at-a-glance that this is a Variable.

Comment: This helped me to have the image passed to Salesforce API from Canvas app.. But I have another issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68460941/parse-json-action-in-flow-fails-from-the-powerapp that when no images are uploaded it throws Parse_JSON failed error