# Parse JSON action in Flow fails from the PowerApp

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, powerapps-canvas

I have a very basic Power App with few input fields and upload image. The app on Submit calls the flow which then passes the submission details to Salesforce. This works fine but when users dont upload the image the flow fails like

```
 Parse_JSON failed -- "message": "Invalid type. Expected String but got Null.",
```

The Submit button logic is like

```
Set(varFileExt, Right(AddImageButton.FileName, 3));
Clear( FormInfo );
Collect(FormInfo,
    {
        idOrNameDetail : IdOrNameDetails.Text,
        projectGUID: GUID(),
        picUri: AddedImage.Image,
        picFilename:
            If(
                AddImageButton.FileName = "image.jpg",
                Concatenate(
                    Text(Now(), "[$-en-US]yyyy-mm-dd_hhmmss"),
                    ".jpg"
                ),
                AddImageButton.FileName
            ),
        fileExtension: varFileExt,
        picJSON: 
            If(
                Or(
                    Lower(varFileExt) = "jpg",
                    Lower(varFileExt) = "jpeg"
                ),
                    Mid(JSON(AddedImage.Image, IncludeBinaryData), 25, Len(JSON(AddedImage.Image, IncludeBinaryData)) - 25),
                
                Lower(varFileExt) = "png",
                    Mid(JSON(AddedImage.Image, IncludeBinaryData), 24, Len(JSON(AddedImage.Image, IncludeBinaryData)) - 24)
            )
    }
);

Set(FormObj, JSON(FormInfo, IncludeBinaryData));
SFIncidentCreation.Run(FormObj);    

Reset(IdOrNameDetails);
Reset(AddImageButton);
```

How can I compose the JSON checking the image is added or not. Any help is greatly appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying save only one record, in this case is better to use a Cotext variable than a Colecction.

```
     UpdateContext({   myData: {
              idOrNameDetail : IdOrNameDetails.Text,
              projectGUID: GUID(),
              picUri: AddedImage.Image,
              picFilename: If(
                 AddImageButton.FileName = "image.jpg",
                 Concatenate(Text(Now(), "[$-en-US]yyyy-mm-dd_hhmmss"),".jpg"),
                 AddImageButton.FileName
              ),
              fileExtension: Right(AddImageButton.FileName, 3),
              picJSON: If(
                 Or(Lower(varFileExt) = "jpg",Lower(varFileExt) = "jpeg"),
                 Mid(
                    JSON(AddedImage.Image, IncludeBinaryData),
                    25,
                    Len(JSON(AddedImage.Image, IncludeBinaryData)) - 25
                 ),
                 Lower(varFileExt) = "png", 
                 Mid(
                    JSON(AddedImage.Image, IncludeBinaryData),
                    24,
                    Len(JSON(AddedImage.Image, IncludeBinaryData)) - 24
                 )
              )
           }
      });
Set(FormObj, JSON(myData));
SFIncidentCreation.Run(FormObj);
Reset(IdOrNameDetails);
Reset(AddImageButton);
```

Comment: Still the Pare_JSON in the PowerAutomate(Flow) fails. Saying expected is string but received null. When users dont upload image how can handle it

Answer (score 0):

**Couple ideas:**

1. Remove `picJSON` as a `required` field from the `Parse_JSON` schema
2. Put a condition before the `Parse_JSON` action that checks whether the field is null or not then acts appropriately.